# What's the difference between 后 and 以后?

Tags: mandarin, synonyms, time

I was taught that so as to say "after" in Chinese one should use 以后, like this:

> 吃饭以后

Today I came across a bare 后, like this:

> 15分钟后

What's the difference between these two words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 后= after

Examples:

吃饭后 = after eating dinner

15分钟后 = after 15 minutes

> 以后 = after

以后 (after) emphasizes on 'time after a specific event or action'

Examples:

吃过**那顿**晚饭以后 = after eating **that** dinner (a specific dinner is emphasized)

**15分钟的沉默**以后 = after **15 minutes of silence** (the event- 15 minutes of silence is emphasized)

> 以后 = 此后 (hereafter); 其后 (thereafter) ; 以来(since)

Example: 自二战**以后** = 自二战**以来** = since WWII

> 以后 = 今后 (from now on)

Example:

我**以后**不再和你说话 = I won't talk to you **from now on**

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference is, 后 can also mean behind, the back, the last, whereas 以后 does not take such a meaning.

后面： behind
*以后面 X （not a word)

房后有个车库。 Behind the house is a garage.
我坐在后排。 I'm sitting in the last (the behind) row.

后, 以后 both can mean after, afterwards, later.

后 can also mean children, as in 后生，'those born after' 九零后 'the children of the 90s'

And of course, 'the woman behind the king' i.e. the queen: 帝王的妻子：皇后，太后

Answer (score 0):

后(after,behind), a single character, connotes **time** or **position** according to the context. When it refers to **time** sequencing, it's the same as 以后. It's like in your examples: 吃饭（以）后, 15分钟(以)后. But in 身后，房后 and etc, you can not replace 后 with 以后， because it stands for the location.

以后(after) only connotes **position**.